# React on (before) datatemplate change - Or prevent listbox item change at this moment

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

In my application I'm using a simple view selector using datatemplates, I basically have a content control and datatemplates like

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:OverviewViewModel}">
        <local:OverviewView></local:OverviewView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DetailViewModel}">
        <local:DetailView></local:DetailView>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Simple, efficient and easily extendable. (Key point is that these usercontrol views can be recursive). The main view also holds a few button with commands behind them to go to "another view".

The problem is, the `DetailView` contains a `ListBox` (`ListView` to be exact), at which "selected items" is of actual importance for the application state. 
Now I notice that if I switch from the DetailView to the `OverviewView` the `SelectionChanged` event fires - actually unselecting all elements. Looking through the callstack this is due to the fact that the actual elements inside the `ListView` are updated, the listview is being cleared when the datatemplate changes.

Now since this actually changes the application state this is bad. (The user didn't actually click to unselect the elements, the selection is one of the main reasons to actually open the detail view).

I've tried catching the `Unloaded` event from the `ListBox`: this event is indeed fired. But also AFTER the selectionchanged event is fired, so it doesn't really help here.

So can I hook up to a "this `UserControl` will be unloaded momentarily" event? The bigger `UserControl` (and the ViewModel for that) should be considered a black box from the smaller `DetailView`/`DetailViewModel`.

Comment: If your problem is really about Selection state for every elements, why not fully handling it in the MV model?

Comment: @Bob Basically I bound the selection to a "selected items" list in the viewmodel, which keeps it together with a list in the model. (Model has a list of "items" - as subset of all items, selection <=> items-in-model). If I fully handle it in the viewmodel the viewmodel becomes brittle and actual dependent on view.